# Spotlight search to Bluetooth settings hindered by "Bluetooth file exchange"

Tags: bluetooth, spotlight, macos

My issue is as small as they get, but I like optimising my workflow. So I go to my Bluetooth settings multiple times a day; to switch headphones or when some other wireless peripheral acts up. I do this via Spotlight search and then type "blu". But then it finds "Bluetooth file exchange", and only after a second or two it shows a list of other options, like so:

[image: Spotlight: blu]

So I have to wait 2 seconds every time; instead of the usual fraction of a second. I figured I just change the name to "File Exchange Bluetooth" or something, but that doesn't seem possible.

What do?

*P.S.: According to XKCD I'm allowed to allot 2 hours to solving this problem.*

[image]

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use Spotlight? If speed is the issue, you can create a keyboard shortcut to open the bluetooth sys prefs via an applescript.

Comment: If there are no other possibilities sure, but my preference is Spotlight. Can't I change the name of the program in terminal or something?

Comment: Nope

`:/Applications/Utilities$ sudo mv Bluetooth\ File\ Exchange.app/ File\ Exchange\ Bluetooth.app/
mv: rename Bluetooth File Exchange.app/ to File Exchange Bluetooth.app/: Operation not permitted`

Comment: So many things I like about this visiting this web page today, thank you @Herman

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can fix this by adding **Bluetooth File Exchange** to Spotlight's exclusion list.

1. In Finder, open `/Applications/Utilities`
2. Navigate to the Spotlight Privacy section:

   - **For macOS Ventura and newer**

     1. Go to **System Settings**
     2. Choose the **Siri & Spotlight** tab.
     3. Select **Spotlight Privacy**  [image: Screenshot of System Settings window with selections highlighted]
   - For **older versions** of macOS:

     1. Go to **System Preferences**
     2. Choose the **Spotlight** preferences
     3. Select the **Privacy** tab
3. Drag in **Bluetooth File Exchange** from Finder to the **Privacy** window to exclude it from Spotlight

[image: Screenshot of Spotlight Privacy window]

Now try Spotlight again with "blu":

[image: Screenshot of Spotlight in use, with "blu" entered and "Bluetooth" appearing as the first option, as desired.]

If any other apps come up before Bluetooth preferences, drag them also into the Spotlight privacy pane.

Note: The reason this works is because what appears to be an App in macOS is actually a folder, although you'd have to right-click it in Finder and `Show Package Contents` to see that).

Comment: Solved it! And I think as a whole I spend about an hour on this issue. So in about 2,5 years it will have paid off ^^

Comment: Is this intended? You can't add the app by clicking '+' and going through the menu.
I just did it by dragging Bluetooth File Exchange to the Privacy tab, but it still shows up in Spotlight

Comment: Updating to Catalina actually removed it from the tab. I had to readd it again. Still a great solution though.

Comment: I can't begin to tell you how much joy this solution brings.

Comment: its 2022 and that fix still works. Why can't they just add a recently used counter or something. A few lines of code!

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your Spotlight search:

`bl p` works for Bluetooth

`ss` or `s s` works for Screen Sharing

`a s` for App Store (usually)